# How to hide shadow in custom shapes in CardView?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have been working on a project and the requirement demands me to have a semi-circular cut on the sides in a **card view** .
I have tried this a lot. I request the experts to help me out with side cut and it's shadow removal.
My output :

See output of my code

[image]

Ideal output

[image]

Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="8dp"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="10dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
    android:background="#a9a9a9"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-22dp"
            android:background="@drawable/coupon_border"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/sample1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
          <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is a long title."
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:textColor="#605f5f"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/view"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, justo habemus      partiendo id has, et stet labore mediocrem pro. "
                android:maxLines="2"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>




</RelativeLayout>
```

Coupon Border xml file :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="oval"
  android:useLevel="false" >
  <stroke
    android:width="2dip"
    android:color="#a9a9a9"/>
 <size
    android:height="30dp"
    android:width="30dp" />
 </shape>
```

Comment: Try to delete `card_view:cardElevation="8dp"` from your CardView or set it as `0dp`

Comment: Okay. But that won't help with the part where cut out part of card is still visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Hope this will work.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
android:background="#a9a9a9"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
android:id="@+id/view"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
```

Comment: how to remove the shadow from the cutout part and add it in the semi circle part then ?

Comment: so you are trying to remove shadow from all places except semi circle ??

Comment: I am trying to remove shadow from the part which should not be visible after the semi circle is placed. In order to make it look like the idea image

Comment: It is created using 9 patch image